# Using radio buttons to add set number to a gridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm looking to add a number to my gridview using a radio button but I'm sure how

Select a radio button that adds 4 and it will display like this. Will only enter the data after using a button.

[image]

**Expected**

The results section should display 3

[image]

Comment: Is this winforms or WPF? However I would imagine you can change what's displayed on your grid by hooking something to the radio's onchange event and finalize it using enter.

Comment: Windows form app

Answer (score 0):

You can assign all radio buttons to the same group (To select only one rb), and Update the case in the row of the gridview with the first number from the selected radio button name:

```
   int results = 0;
        foreach(RadioButton rb in groupBox1.Controls)
        {
            if (rb.Checked)
            {
                results = int.Parse(rb.Text.Substring(0,1)); //You can change it if result >= 10
                break;
            }
        }
```

Now Add a Row in the DataGridView with the Player/Event/Result values on Enter button click.

Comment: I have it setup so it will add the row (Player, Event and Result) already. I just want to make it so it will add the set amount of points selected to the new row when enter is pressed.

Comment: you need to update the Result case in the DataGridView when pressing Enter?

Comment: gyazo.com/ab786a84fe5a0f66fd97e2f6707dbef1 example of what I want to do. (Radio button will set the result number)

Comment: use the code above to get the result value from the checked radio button.

Comment: Added the radio buttons to a group box and changed gridscore to the gridbox name. Thank you for your help! Sorry for being stupid

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `radioButton.CheckedChanged` then when they checkbox is checked then you using a method to send the value that is assigned to the checkbox to your GridView.